# spark xml: need struct type but got string;

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a folder which consists from XML files and we assume that these files has the same structure. But some of these files are incomplete due to errors in the application which generates these files:

*Expected structure:*

```
root
 |-- R: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- LTI: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- C: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- V: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- MFV: string (nullable = true)
```

*Needs to be ignored structure:*

```
root
 |-- R: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- LTI: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- MFV: string (nullable = true)
```

That is how I parse

```
df = spark.read \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml") \
  .options(rowTag="RList") \
  .load("/mnt/data/uploads/*/*/*/RList.xml")

df.select(
  "R.LTI.C", 
  "R.LTI.V", 
  "R.MFV", 
).show()
```

That is what I catch when it tries to load incomplete XML

```
Can't extract value from R#204.LTI: need struct type but got string;"
```

**My question is how to ignore such kind of files?**

Comment: how did you get `df`

Comment: I added the code how I got df

Comment: Did you find out the answer?

Comment: @mrvol if i remember it correctly, in this particular case, i decided to use RDD where i can control parsing process, where with XPath I grab what i need.

Comment: @AlexS Thanks a lot!